# Installing Nvidia drivers on Linux Mint 15

Tags: drivers, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I'm a Linux newbie and any help and links are appreciated.

My problem is that I cannot find any stable way to install proprietary nVidia drivers on my system (Linux Mint 15). Is there some tutorial existing about how can I make it with simple `apt-get install`?

**UPDATE:** Just to clarify, if it matters, "System Info" says that I have **two video cards**:

- Graphics Card 0: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
- Graphics Card 1: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M]

Comment: Did you check the Linux mint forums? http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=120448

Answer (score 1):

Try install with command.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-update
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

After a restart, if is presented with a `640x480` screen. This is due to the [DKMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) not auto detecting the horizontal and vertical scanning frequency of the monitor. Edit the video settings file manually.

```
gksudo kate /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

In the file, locate:  Section `Monitor` and increase the horizontal sync and vertical refresh frequency.

```
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "Monitor0"
   VendorName "Unknown"
   ModelName "Unknown"
   HorizSync 28.0 - 72.0
   VertRefresh 43.0 - 60.0
EndSection
```

<sub>[(Reference)](http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/hardware/installing-nvidia-drivers-in-linux-mint)</sub>

Comment: I did as you suggested. I don't know if drivers were installed (Driver Manager says that no proprietary drivers were installed) and when I log in I'm seeing message "Cinnamon just crashed. You are currently running in Fallback Mode. Yes/No" and Cinnamon is not started. Any idea what this can be?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this repositoy:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```